# What is the risk of leaking iphone "serial numbers"?

Tags: privacy, iphone

Should I worry if my "serial number" is leaked? What could an attacker do with it? Social Hacking? Real Hacking?

Comment: A device serial number is not enough to try to connect with it

Comment: I think you only need it for warranty and similar stuff. I would also look up whether it somehow relates to Apple Pay somehow